# ADLS move files to a parent directory

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

Lets say I have around 5TB of files in adls folder(ADLS Gen2). Folder structure is like this

files/country/

Now all the files belong to US region and I want to add one more folder in the hierarchy, kind of like this.

files/country/USA/

How to achieve this in the fastest and cost most cost efficient manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Factory.

Select `DataFlow` Activity. In Source Settings Select `Key` as Set partitioning.

Now select `Country` column in Unique value per partition.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow-write-to-lake#hierarchical-folder-output

Comment: I am looking for some cli commands, plus assume there is no country column